# Equivalent of similar to ~ of postgres in hql

Tags: sql, postgresql, jpa, hql

Is there any equivalent of [similar to (~)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-matching.html) operator in hql?

Comment: Are you still using postgresql under the hoods (or does it need to work with other RDBMS now)?

Comment: i am using postgres as backend.

Comment: I need to use named parameter for comparison in hql.

Comment: JPQL has LIKE as per any JPA docs. Anything other than that is outside the scope of JPA, so you lose vendor independence, and datastore independence